# Stackoverflow exception from updating combobox in winforms/C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, stack-overflow

I'm geting a `StackOverflowException`. Somehow, posting here seemed appropriate.

I'm using Windows Forms in a C# application. This application is intended to run on Linux, FreeBSD and Mac-OS, so I can't use WPF, so please don't suggest it.

My guess is that I'm missing a nuance of WinForms, but I cant seem to figure out what.

The `ComboBox` is generated by the GUI form builder in VS 2010.

The specific lines of code that are throwing the error are here:

```
if(cur_num_is_valid)
{
    cbx_material_num.Text = num;
}
else
{
    num = "0";
    //I only have one of the following two at a time. Both overflow
    cbx_material_num.SelectedIndex = 0;
    cbx_material_num.Text = "0";
}
```

Since the code is somewhat complex, here's the whole function code.  'cbx_' indicates a combo box.  'txtb_' is a text box.

```
private void cbx_material_numobj_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string obj = cbx_material_obj.Text;
    string num = cbx_material_num.Text;
    int selnum = 0;
    int n = 0;

    //do we need to recreate the numbers array?
    bool cur_num_is_valid = false;
    cbx_material_num.Items.Clear();
    if(obj != lastobj)
    {
        n = m_demo.get_object_modifiers(obj);
        for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            string s = i.ToString();
            if(s == num && i < n) cur_num_is_valid = true;
            cbx_material_num.Items.Add(s);
        }
    }
    if(cur_num_is_valid)
    {
        cbx_material_num.Text = num;
    }
    else
    {
        num = "0";
        //Overflow here:
        cbx_material_num.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    try
    {
        selnum = int.Parse(num);
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error, second select menu after 'object modifiers' must be a number, not '"+num+"'.");
        cbx_material_num.Text="0";
        return;
    }

    if(selnum >= n)
    {
        txtb_material_param1.Text = "0";
        txtb_material_param2.Text = "0";
        txtb_material_param3.Text = "0";
        txtb_material_param4.Text = "0";
    }
    else
    {
        MaterialFace face;
        MaterialParameter parameter;
        int typeid;
        object paramdata;
        m_demo.get_object_modifiers_material(obj, selnum, out face, out parameter, out typeid, out paramdata);
        cbx_material_face.Text = face.ToString();
        cbx_material_paramtype.Text = parameter.ToString();
        switch(typeid)
        {
            case 0:
                txtb_material_param1.Text = ((float)paramdata).ToString();
                cbx_material_datatype.Text = "float";
                goto case -1;
            case 1:
                float[] parsf = ((float[])paramdata);
                txtb_material_param1.Text = parsf[0].ToString();
                txtb_material_param2.Text = parsf[1].ToString();
                txtb_material_param3.Text = parsf[2].ToString();
                txtb_material_param4.Text = parsf[3].ToString();
                cbx_material_datatype.Text = "float[]";
                break;
            case 2:
                txtb_material_param1.Text = ((int)paramdata).ToString();
                cbx_material_datatype.Text = "int";
                goto case -1;
            case 3:
                int[] parsi = ((int[])paramdata);
                txtb_material_param1.Text = parsi[0].ToString();
                txtb_material_param2.Text = parsi[1].ToString();
                txtb_material_param3.Text = parsi[2].ToString();
                txtb_material_param4.Text = parsi[3].ToString();
                cbx_material_datatype.Text = "int[]";
                break;
            case -1: //can't actuall be returned, used to 'blank' the last three as '0'
                txtb_material_param2.Text = "0";
                txtb_material_param2.Text = "0";
                txtb_material_param3.Text = "0";
                break;
            case 4:
                OpenTK.Graphics.Color4 paramc = ((OpenTK.Graphics.Color4)paramdata);
                txtb_material_param1.Text = paramc.R.ToString();
                txtb_material_param2.Text = paramc.G.ToString();
                txtb_material_param3.Text = paramc.B.ToString();
                txtb_material_param4.Text = paramc.A.ToString();
                cbx_material_datatype.Text = "Color4";
                break;
            default: //5
                Vector4 paramv = ((Vector4)paramdata);
                txtb_material_param1.Text = paramv.X.ToString();
                txtb_material_param2.Text = paramv.Y.ToString();
                txtb_material_param3.Text = paramv.Z.ToString();
                txtb_material_param4.Text = paramv.W.ToString();
                cbx_material_datatype.Text = "Vector4";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions about Stack Overflow belong on meta.stackoverflow.com. ;)

Comment: This is not a meta question. A StackOverflowException is when there are too many calls in the stack. The Stackoverflow indicates that the dropdownlist is recurisvely calling itself `cbx_material_numobj_SelectedIndexChanged`. To avoid the recursive calls create a Private Member Bool variable called IsRecursive and exit the function if it is calling itself.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check that the SelectedIndex isn't already 0 before you try to set it:

```
    if (cbx_material_num.SelectedIndex != 0){
       cbx_material_num.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

Otherwise you're re-firing the event every time through.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. and in this context it almost certainly always will be.

Answer (score 0):

I think that whenever you set this `cbx_material_num.SelectedIndex = 0;` within the `EventHandler` you invoke your

```
cbx_material_numobj_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Each call invokes another eventHandler so the stack fills up after some time.
Basically, the fact that it is called SelectedIndexChanged doesn't mean that the value has to be different from the previous one but that the value is set through its setter.

Comment: if that is the case, use SelectionChangeCommitted instead. It only fires if the user changes the value via the gui.